# Stream upload data using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on a system that is basically acting as a layer between the user and other backend services.  One of the operations I need to support is file uploading.  Ideally I want to have the data being uploaded to be streamed in real-time through PHP to the appropriate backend services.  Unfortunately due to the way PHP handles multipart encoded POST requests, I can't find a way to make this happen.

Is there a way to disable PHP's automatic handling (and/or blocking) on multipart requests?
Is there another way I could accomplish my goal of having this data stream through PHP?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. If you want to handle raw requests handle it from CGI.

Comment: Unfortunately the places the data needs to go are a number of API's which have been implemented in PHP.  To move this out of PHP would require a significant cost.

Comment: Perhaps you will not have to move away from the PHP. I've done once this what you are describing but in python. I can imagine you can have a CGI script written in PHP. It will handle the raw request. Alternatively you can even write a small socket server and handle requests on the lowest level.